# A star or Flow? Solutions?

Tags: graph, path-finding, a-star

Algorithm for game?

I have a house with N*M rooms. I have K enemies in house and R sets of bombs, each set with a cost. I must eliminate all enemies by detonating sets of bombs as many are needed but with minimal total cost. After a set of bombs is detonated, we can detonate again the same set of bombs, and after a detonation all enemies must move in a direction North, South, West or East.

How can i find this minimal total cost?

N*M <= 60 and I need to find a answer in t < 0.95s.

I was thinking to make a tree with initial house(matrix) root and R children with

- house 1 after detonation of Set of bombs 1 and enemies moves (if a enemy is not dead, we put it in all 4 direction)
- house 2 after detonation of set of bombs 2 and so on.

And for each children continue with this expand until i find a empty house. Could this be a solution? For me looks good but i think it will take more then 1 sec.

Example input:

N M K R
where:
N - number of rows
M - number of columns
K - number of enemies
R - number of sets of bombs

next K rows: positions of K enemies pX pY

next R rows: Ci Ri x1 y1 … xri yri
where
Ci - cost of set i
Ri - number of bombs(rooms)
xi, yi - coordonates of bombs (rooms)

```
4 3 2 2
1 1
2 1
5 4 0 1 1 0 1 2 2 1
20 4 1 1 2 0 2 2 3 1
```

And the answer is 10 beacause we choose Set 1 with cost 5, 2 times

Comment: You should include the effects of the bombs as it may be possible to use bomb on multiple enemies, but that's only possible if it's known how effective a bomb is. Is a bomb effective at clearing a single room or multiple rooms?

Comment: A bomb kill all enemies in the room (a set of bombs for example are the rooms that will be clearing)

Comment: How many bombs are in each of the R sets? Or do you actually mean that there are only R bombs? Also is it correct that each room only needs a single bomb placed it in to kill anyone who enters that room? You should also probably give a small example.

Comment: I update de question!

Comment: Your strategy seems sound then. Although, you should made sure to place all of the bombs then expand outward from each enemy until either the expansion is blocked by bombs or there aren't enough bombs to halt the expansion. Find the lowest cost seems a bit more difficult though. Good luck.